# expo-app-loading is deprecated in favor of expo-splash-screen

Tags: expo

I'm taking on a research project that uses expo to develop a mobile application. However, I am facing the following error *expo-app-loading is deprecated in favor of SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() instead*. and I don't know how to solve it. I was able to map and see that this error is coming from this part of the code:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

import DailyLog from "../../models/DailyLog";

export const FETCH_RECORD = "FETCH_RECORD";
export const FETCH_OR_CREATE_RECORD = "FETCH_OR_CREATE_RECORD";
export const FETCH_DAILY_LOGS = "FETCH_DAILY_LOGS";

export const SAVE_LOG = "SAVE_LOG";
export const SAVE_LOG_COMMIT = "SAVE_LOG_COMMIT";
export const SAVE_LOG_ROLLBACK = "SAVE_LOG_ROLLBACK";

export const UPDATE_RECORD = "UPDATE_RECORD";
export const UPDATE_RECORD_ROLLBACK = "UPDATE_RECORD_ROLLBACK";

export const LOAD_RECORD = "LOAD_RECORD";
export const LOAD_DAILY_LOGS = "LOAD_DAILY_LOGS";

import moment from "moment";
import Localhost from "../../constants/Localhost";
import Traducao from "../../components/Traducao/Traducao";

export const fetchRecord = () => {
    console.log("fetchRecord")

    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const token = getState().user.token;
        const userId = getState().user.currentUser.id;

        const responseRecord = await fetch(
            `http://${Localhost.address}${Localhost.port}/aes/webresources/secured/record/find/${userId}`,
            {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
            }
        );

        if (!responseRecord.ok) {
            throw new Error(Traducao.t("getRegistryError"));
        }
        //console.log("Aqui")
        let record = await responseRecord.json();
        //console.log(record)
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_RECORD,
            recordId: record.id,
            dailyGoal: record.dailyGoal,
            weeklyGoal: record.weeklyGoal,
            userId: userId,
        });
    };
};
```

Can anyone help me? I am using expo version 6.0.1 and the project is on SDK version 45.

Comment: Does this solve your issue?
[How to load custom fonts with the useFonts hook in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172404)

Answer (score 0):

you should use SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() instead.
The expo-app-loading package is used to display a loading screen when the app starts.so you need to update your code to use the new API.

you can use SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() to prevent the splash screen from hiding automatically:

```
import { SplashScreen } from 'expo';

// Call this function in your component's useEffect or componentDidMount lifecycle method.
const preventAutoHide = async () => {
await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
}
```

Note that you may need to import the SplashScreen module from the expo package and call preventAutoHide in your component's lifecycle method.

Also, make sure to call SplashScreen.hideAsync() when you're ready to hide the splash screen, or you can use SplashScreen.hide() if your app is using Expo SDK version >=33.0.0.